# Как не загружать Glide дважды при повороте экрана?

Tags: android, glide

Помогите, пожалуйста. Как не загружать Glide дважды при повороте экрана используя viewModel? Использовал LiveData, но что-то не получилось) В фрагмент у меня прилетает url, используя который я загружаю картинку. Спасибо за ответы!

```
class CatInfoFragment : Fragment() {

    private var url: String? = null
    private var _binding: CatInfoBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
 
  
    

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        url = arguments?.getString(URL)

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val catInfoImageView: ImageView = binding.imageView
        saveButton = binding.floatingActionButton
        Glide.with(requireActivity())
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cat_empty)
            .into(catInfoImageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

При повороте экрана View уничтожается и создается заново, если ты не хочешь загружать картинку из сети два раза, то настрой кэширование

```
Glide.with(fragment)
  .load(url)
  .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
  .into(imageView);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]